# Loop to replace all non-blank values in certain variables in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyr, na

How would I be able to run a loop to set all NA values to FALSE and all non-NA values to TRUE in the variables which are in a separate list?

example dataframe:

```
| var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | email | NA | b|
| name | email | a| b|
| name | email | a| NA|
| name | email | NA| b|
| name | email | a| b|
| name | email | a| NA|
```

```
list.vars <- list("var3", "var4")
```

example outcome dataframe:

```
| var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | email | FALSE| TRUE|
| name | email | TRUE| TRUE|
| name | email | TRUE| FALSE|
| name | email | FALSE| TRUE|
| name | email | TRUE| TRUE|
| name | email | TRUE| FALSE|
```

Comment: `dplyr::mutate(across(list_here, ~ifelse(is.na(.),1,0))` not tested though.

Comment: Could you share your data with `dput` for better reproducibility? Is your data `NA` or `chr`?

Comment: If char: `df %>% 
   mutate(across(unlist(list.vars), ~ifelse(grepl("NA",.),FALSE,TRUE)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(var3:var4, ~ ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE, TRUE)))
  var1  var2  var3  var4
1 name email FALSE  TRUE
2 name email  TRUE  TRUE
3 name email  TRUE FALSE
4 name email FALSE  TRUE
5 name email  TRUE  TRUE
6 name email  TRUE FALSE
```

Data used:

```
df
  var1  var2 var3 var4
1 name email <NA>    b
2 name email    a    b
3 name email    a <NA>
4 name email <NA>    b
5 name email    a    b
6 name email    a <NA>
```

Comment: why not `!`: `df %>% mutate(across(unlist(list.vars), ~ !is.na(.)))`.

Comment: This worked using across(first(list):last(list) ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your dataframe is called `df`

```
for (v in list.vars){
  df[[paste0(v,"_result")]] <- df[[v]] %>% is.na() %>% `!`
}
```